# Automotive: For what purpose ISO-TP Extended Addressing is used?

Tags: can-bus, iot-for-automotive

I've read through all ISO documents and can't figure out in which cases we need extended addressing in ISO-TP, though I've seen packets from BMW CAN traffic where UDS uses extended addressing.

Why does ISO-TP protocol need to specify target address if all nodes do the filtering by CAN ID? Is it possible that nodes will also filter packed by ISO-TP target address?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

ISO 15765-2 (ISO-TP) is a transport protocol over CAN, so it needs to use its own address for specific purpose.
When ISO 15765-2 need to refer to one single node, it uses CAN address as ISO-TP  address. When it has to send information throught a gateway, it uses extended address, taking one CAN Payload Byte to specify gateway address (only have 7 bytes left for data).

Answer (score -3):

ISO-TP protocol allows for the transport of messages that exceed the eight-byte maximum payload of CAN frames. ISO-TP segments longer messages into multiple frames, adding metadata that allows the interpretation of individual frames and reassembly into a complete message packet by the recipient. It can carry up to 4095 bytes of payload per message packet.

Comment: The question was about Extended UDS addressing (Addressing Information is carried by CAN ID and Target Address byte - in the first CAN frame data byte).